# Google chart error when hideColumns[1]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-visualization

I'm under creating google linechart with jquery for hide/show column of data.
but i'm stuck in this problem when click on first data checkbox using hideColumns[1](http://jsfiddle.net/dyaskur/dwrcer45/) is always error but if hideColumns[2] and hideColumns[3] are not error.

```
            $(document).ready(function () {
            // do stuff on "ready" event
            $(".checkbox").change(function() {

                view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

                view.setColumns([0, 1,
                    { calc: "stringify",
                        sourceColumn: 1,
                        type: "string",
                        role: "annotation" },2,
                    { calc: "stringify",
                        sourceColumn: 2,
                        type: "string",
                        role: "annotation" },3,
                    { calc: "stringify",
                        sourceColumn: 3,
                        type: "string",
                        role: "annotation" }]);
                if(!$("#kolom1").is(':checked'))
                    view.hideColumns([1]);
                if(!$("#kolom2").is(':checked'))
                    view.hideColumns([2]);
                if(!$("#kolom3").is(':checked'))
                    view.hideColumns([3]);

                chart.draw(view, options);

            });
        });
```

the error in chrome said:

> "Failed to execute 'replaceChild' on 'Node'"

but if other checkbox(hideColumns[2] and hideColumns[3]) is no problem, how to fix it? you can try at jsfiddle below:

[view on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dyaskur/dwrcer45/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

after trial and error i solved my own question with code below

```
           $(document).ready(function () {
            // do stuff on "ready" event
            $(".checkbox").change(function() {

                view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
                var tes =[0];

                if($("#kolom1").is(':checked')) {

                    tes.push(1,
                        { calc: "stringify",
                            sourceColumn: 1,
                            type: "string",
                            role: "annotation" });                    }
                if($("#kolom2").is(':checked'))
                {
                    tes.push(2,
                        { calc: "stringify",
                            sourceColumn: 2,
                            type: "string",
                            role: "annotation" });
                }
                if($("#kolom3").is(':checked'))
                {
                    tes.push(3,
                        { calc: "stringify",
                            sourceColumn: 3,
                            type: "string",
                            role: "annotation" });
                }
                view.setColumns(tes);


                chart.draw(view, options);

            });
        });
```

hope useful [view on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dyaskur/q1rppjx0/)